# Vector Operators?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$ \overrightarrow {F}=3xz^{2}i+2xyj-x^{2}k $$ $$\phi =3x^{2}-yz $$ are given vector and scalar fields, respectively.

a) $\quad \operatorname{div}\left( \operatorname{grad}\phi \operatorname{div}\overrightarrow {F}\right) =\quad? $

b) $\quad \operatorname{curl}\left( \phi F\right) =\quad? $

c) $\quad \operatorname{div}\left( \phi F\right) =\quad? $

d) $\quad \overrightarrow {\nabla }\cdot \left( \nabla \phi \times \overrightarrow {F}\right) =\quad? $

e) $\quad \nabla \cdot \left( \overrightarrow {F}\nabla \phi \right) =\quad? $

I know the operations such as the Gradient, Divergence, Curl, and Laplacian. But I don't have an idea what can I do in this kind of problems?

Comment: are all of those $x$ $y$ and $z$'s supposed to be lowercase?

Comment: Yes.All characters are lowercase.

Comment: Not sure what in particular has you confused.  All of these problems involve only divergences, gradients, curls, and dot or cross products, all of which you should be able to do. Can you explain in more detail what has you stuck?

Comment: for example : a) I found gradient of scalar field and divergence of vector field.Gradient of scalar field is a vector and divergence of vector fields is a scalar.So how can I take the divergence of this?

Comment: Here is what I have found for a)
= (18z^2-12+72x+2z-6z^2+2y-6yz) + (24-4z-3z^2-8y+2x-6xz) + (36xz+36x^2-9z^2-4y+2x-12xz-6yz-6xy) 

= 36x^2-6xy-12yz+6y+18xz

Comment: I think there are a few mistakes,correct answer from wolframalpha is  in here : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%2818z%5E2-12%2B72x%2B2z-6z%5E2%2B2y-6yz%29+%2B+%2824-4z-3z%5E2-8y%2B2x-6xz%29+%2B+%2836xz%2B36x%5E2-9z%5E2-4y%2B2x-12xz-6yz-6xy%29.